# Using a CursorAdapter with two different ContentProviders

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I would like to display a list of contacts.

I would like to pull those contacts from Android's contacts `ContentProvider` (as defined by `ContactsContract`) as well as a table of contacts managed by my own app (for which I've also defined a `ContentProvider`).

Ideally I would like to produce a single `Cursor` that represents a union of queries from both sources.

If I had full access to Android's contacts table, I would use a SQL UNION. As it is, I believe that that is impossible/bad practice to perform a raw SQL query on a database that doesn't belong to your own app.

Alternatively, is there a straight forward way to define a `CursorWrapper` extension which would iterate over one cursor before moving onto the next?

I would accept any means of ending up with a single `Cursor` object for these two sources or an elegant outline for an implementation of an `Adapter` which would deliver the same result.

Comment: MergeCursor ....

Comment: Sounds perfect. No idea how I missed this.